# c# and Sybase. Error when creating many tables

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, sybase

In C# I run a massive create table script in Sybase and my program hangs after around 47 create table statements run. I send the statements to the database one at a time and dispose of my command and connection object each time.

Think it might have to do with the allowable cache size in Sybase

So when I send 47 create statements to the database it hangs and when I send 46 it runs ok

I guess it must be some cache value that I need to increase or flush the cache or something along those lines

The exact same thing happens when I run the script using Interactive SQL i.e. it hangs on around the 47th create table statement

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't envy you, having to use Sybase.

Comment: It will help if you mention what version of Sybase. There are different settings between 12 and 15, for example.

Comment: If it hangs on the 47th one, if you move that one first, will it then run the first one as normal, and then hang on the 46th (that is now in 47th place) ?

Comment: Do you close the connection before disposing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would not create and close the connection after each SQL statement. Just leave the connection open until you are finished. Maybe it's you actual 47th SQL statement that is invalid.